# DHCP server on a multi ip interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireshark, dhcp-server

My system runs Ubuntu 17.04, my network topology is:

[image: network topology]

I have eth1 configured with multiple IP addresses:

```
$ ip addr show eth1
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:c8:3d:19:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.123.52/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.55.1/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::280:c8ff:fe3d:1994/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I use the net on eth1 to develop and test my equipment, and I have a DHCP server configured as follow:

```
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.55.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.55.100 192.168.55.150;
}
```

When te DUT connected to eth1 ask for an ip address, the DHCP server respond and offer, but sniffing with Wireshark the packets have source address 169.254.123.52:

[image: wireshark trace]

Two questions:

1. how to make DHCP sever running only on eth1?
2. How to make packet come from DHCP on eth1 have source address 192.168.55.1?

Answer (score 0):

You might try
`server-identifier 192.168.55.1`

This is not recommended by the man page, your configuration is exactly the use case it describes.

*This* (my previous answer) will cause DHCPD to bind to a single IP address, and as you noted, will break broadcast requests:

`local-address`:

e.g.

`local-address 192.168.55.1`

Comment: this does not work. The sever bind on 192.168.55.1 so it accept request addressed to 192.168.55.1, and also broadcast are dropped